# Spring Boot @RedisHash keys are persisted

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am using **spring-data-redis** to store and retrieve data with TTL. I can see multiple entries where one entry is always persisted which is maintaining KEYS (@Id annotated value). Looks like Redis keeps track of keys as separate entry. In below image **studentEntity** entry size keeps on increasing. After TTL **studentEntity:studentKey963 information** will be removed but the KEY **studentEntity:studentKey963** is stored in **studentEntity** entry. Any idea how it works and how to clear those persisted entries too ?

[image]

Comment: "Looks like Redis keeps track of keys as separate entry." - It's Spring (spring-data-redis) that does it, not Redis.

Comment: Any idea how to remove that and how not to keep track of those entries ?

Comment: "how to remove that" - Did you try clicking the `X` button?

Comment: "how not to keep track of those entries" - You would have to do your own implementation of relevant interfaces.